# How to redirect non existing routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have switched from an old site with a good page rank to RubyOnRails.

Of course all links are broken now. When a user visits my site via a google link he will get:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/SOME_WRONG/URL/WITH/PARAMETERS"
```

What is the best way to redirect the user on error like that to my root_url?

And where I have to put this code?

```
.htaccess?
application_controller?
application.rb?
routes.rb?
```

many many thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Are you running your live site in development mode? Production should instead be serving a 404 file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the very bottom of config/routes.rb, add a wildcard route that redirects:

```
match "*missing" => redirect("/")
```

Now any unknown routes will finally be caught by this rule and redirected to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Study about the route globbing where all the unidentified routes would be redirected back to the main page of your rails app...

http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/12/rails-route-globbing.html